# Can't access array in sync with Firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, angularfire

I'm developing an Ionic app. Its basicaly a quizz, where users posts answers to some questions.

Here is my database structure

```
user{
    userID (autogenerated by Firebase){
          name:
          surname:
          questionsAnswered:
answers{
       userID (linked with users){
          question1answer:
          question2answer:
          ...
```

As you see, there is no answer ID. I did it like this because i thought i didnt need one. **Please correct me if im wrong**

My users data is in sync with Firebase, but i can't retrieve the data from the answers part.

Here is some code for the controller.

```
.controller('ConcursoCtrl', function($scope, controlDatos, $firebaseArray, $cordovaCamera)

$scope.myAnswers = {};

var uid = "-K5omNwU5rpo1Z4WvpnQ"; //This is just for test purposes

var myAnswersRef = new Firebase('https://url.firebaseio.com/answers/'+ uid);
$scope.myAnswers = $firebaseArray(myAnswersRef);

console.log('Answer 1', $scope.myAnswers.question1answer);
console.log($scope.myAnswers);
```

The **first console log doesn't return anything**. The second log returns as much objects as answers are in the database (checked), so i know am accesing it fine, but i can't get the values of the diferent answers.

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

**¿Am i trying to acces the data wrong with $scope.myAnswers.question1answer?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my own question just in case someone makes the same mistake.

Basically, i was trying to retrieve a single object with $firebaseArray, used to retrieve a array of objects.

Using **$firebaseArray with /root/answers path** I could retrieve **all the questions answered by the users.** This could be too data intensive, as im forcing all users to download all the data (there are pictures stored in firebase).

Instead i just use **$firebaseObject** just to **donwload the single object** that i need.

Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

> As you see, there is no answer ID. I did it like this because i
>   thought i didnt need one. **Please correct me if im wrong**

You actually do have an `answer_id`.

When structuring your data, think about them in conjunction with Security Rules.

```
{
   "answers": {
      "$uid": {
         "$answer_id": {

         }
      }
   }
}
```

This makes a path of `answers/$uid/$answer_id`, so each key under the `$uid` location is an `$answer_id`.

*Now, onto the display problem.*

> The **first console log doesn't return anything.**

You're dealing with asynchronous data, so it hasn't downloaded yet by the time `console.log()` runs. And this is okay, because AngularFire will trigger Angular's `$digest` loop when the data has downloaded.

So all you need to do is attach the `answers` to scope.

```
// create a root ref
var ref = new Firebase('<my-firebase-app>');
// create a ref to the user's answers using .getAuth() and the uid
var myAnswersRef = root.child('answers').child(root.getAuth().uid);
// assign answers to $scope
$scope.answers = $firebaseArray(myAnswersRef);
```

Now you should be able to use this in a template with a simple `ng-repeat`:

```
<ul ng-repeat="answer in answers">
   <li> {{ answer.text }} </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Didn't I attach the Answers to scope with this?

`var myAnswersRef = new Firebase('https://url.firebaseio.com/answers/'+ uid);
$scope.myAnswers = $firebaseArray(myAnswersRef);`

I don't have any autentification in the project, so your answer is returning me "TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of null" even when uid has the key of the user.

I tried to look some info before posting here, but im afraid my knowledge of firebase/angularFire is too low to understand the basics.

Comment: Without the auth it should be something like this, `var myAnswersRef = ref.child('respuestas').child(uid);` rigth? It's doing the same thing and returning `[object Object]`. I tried to call the log from a function, too see if it was a timing thing, but i still get the same.

Comment: Can you turn this into a JSFiddle or Plnkr? That way I can help debug it much easier.

Comment: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/nfwsd2zv/) Here is the jsfiddle. There is a login screen controlled with "InicioCtrl". It's very simple so i didn't put it there. Most variables and stuff is in spanish but is pretty simple. Participante = user. Respuestas = answers. Reto = Question. The wut function is just to get a log of the variables. If i press it in less than one second it returns empty. If i wait a little before pressing it, it returns empty + [object Object]

Comment: Hi again. When i attach the firebase url to "firebaseurl/answers", i'm able to see all the answes doing `<ul ng-repeat="answer in answers ">
       <li> {{ answer.question1answer}} </li>
    </ul>`, but what i get is all the answers of question1answer for all the users. What i need to get is all the answers for one user. I'm sure this is a problem of me not understanding the database. Here is a picture of the database structure. [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16612940/Firebase%20structure.png)